# Does the airlock code have any special meaning?

Tags: plot-explanation, avenue-5

In episode 8 of Avenue 5, the airlock code is exposed: 5335.

Does it have any special meaning?

I didn't find any reference in the show or even Google search, but the number doesn't appear to be random either.

Comment: Why doesn't it appear to be random? It appears completely random to me.

Comment: @Luciano well to start with, two "5" and the name of the show is Avenue **5**. I believe it will be revealed at some point in some interview, didn't find one yet.

Comment: ok but what prompted you to believe the code has any special meaning? Just because it has "5" in it? It sounds a bit like trivia.

Comment: I always look for hidden meanings in movies and TV shows, usually finding them with quick Google search.

Comment: @Luciano and there is in-show reference to an "Avenue 3".

Comment: @AnthonyX ah I must've missed that

Comment: @AnthonyX thanks, but I still didn't find anything "solid" about it. I even looked in Google Street View for the building in the address 5th Avenue New York with number 5335, but alas... nothing special there. :(